# 滅日 meaning and J-J definition problems

Tags: words

> 繁栄にあつく。
>   ルーツは原初からして不明。
>   **滅日**の記憶はない。

Hospitable to flourishing.
Starting from the base, the roots are mysterious.
There are no memories of ??

I looked up that word in a dictionary and could not find anything.
So I tried a J-J Dictionary and found this:

> 陰陽道(オンヨウドウ)で，万事に凶の日。人の生まれ年によって定まるという。

I am not sure I understand this though.
I'll give you my interpretation:
In Omnyou: A day of bad luck for all and everything. Defined by the year in which a person is born.

Is it something like an unlucky day?

Comment: Interesting question! Would you have some more context in order to know whether you can go by “unlucky day”or not. Because I think that it depends on how much the passage relies on onmyoudou. Here 滅日｛めつにち｝ might be used for an image of an unlucky day or for its more precise meaning.

Comment: It's a segment that start like that, where something bad is going to happen.  That's all there is to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think 滅日 is a widely known word, and that dictionary definition is probably irrelevant.

But 滅 literally means "perish" and 日 literally means "day/date", so it could mean "the date of death." I found [this page](http://mai-net.net/bbs/sst/sst.php?act=dump&cate=all&all=1072&n=4) which includes this phrase:

> **誕生の記憶**など無く。繁栄もなく。ルーツは原初からして不明瞭。滅日の記憶も無い。

That part looks almost like a paranoid poem, but "I don't remember (my?) birth nor (my?) death" seems to make sense to me.

"Unlucky" is not the primary meaning of 滅. Some compounds like [仏滅](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%AD%E6%9B%9C) have such a nuance, though.

Comment: Oh thanks, Makes sense. Did I at least understand the dictionary definiton correctly?

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm not sure what "unlucky *day* is determined by the *year* of birth" actually means...